# How to select just some fields from a table in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda, entity-framework-4.1

I have a table with 9 columns in database and I want to be able to load only some fields of it if I need.

How can I do this with Entity Framework 4 please?

e.g. My table has these fields:

```
ID, FirstName, LastName, FotherName, BirthDate, Mobile, Email
```

and I want to be able to fetch just these columns:

```
ID, FirstName, LastName
```

My project is an `ASP.NET MVC 3` application, with `SQLServer 2008 Express` and `EF 4.1`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assume you have a table with this model:

```
public class User{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string NickName {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string FotherName {get; set;}
    public DateTime BirthDate {get; set;}
    public string Mobile {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

Now, you want fetch just `ID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `FotherName`. You can do it in 2 way; The first way is fetch them as an `anonymous` object, look:

```
var user = entityContext.Users.Where(u => u.ID == id)
    .Select(u => new {
        ID = u.ID,
        FirstName = u.FirstName,
        LastName = u.LastName,
        FotherName = u.FotherName
    }).Single();
```

Now, your return-value-type is `anonymous`, you can work with it such as:

```
var i = user.ID;
// or
var s = user.FirstName;
```

In another way (for example when you want to *pass* the object as an **Model** to a **View**), you can define a new class, (i.e. `UserViewModel`), and when you select the object, select it as a `UserViewModel`. look:

```
public class UserViewModel{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string NickName {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string FotherName {get; set;}
}
```

and in query, take this:

```
var user = entityContext.Users.Where(u => u.ID == id)
    .Select(u => new UserViewModel {
        ID = u.ID,
        FirstName = u.FirstName,
        LastName = u.LastName,
        FotherName = u.FotherName
    }).Single();
```

Look that just **ONE** difference is between them, in labda expression, instead of `u => new {}`
we are using `u => new UserViewModel{}`. Good luck.

Comment: Why are we not just using constructors in viewmodels?

Comment: @Java_Amiry how to return list not single

Comment: @SAR just replace the `.Single()` method with `.ToList()` one

Comment: @Javad_Amiry i had tried it should have work but not in my case

Comment: @javadamiry Thanks, `.ToList()` works fine. But when using the code above with `.ToList()` doesn't it load the whole table into application and then only keep the desired column? What if I want to load only the desired column and use it? (Because loading whole table takes much more resources.)

Comment: @farshad nope. that's a common misunderstanding in most coders. the 'ToList' makes the ef to build-up the final query and send it to db, and just loads what did you asked in query. don't worry. use it.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many ways to do this job, but using `Automapper` NuGet package is the most simple one I have experienced.

- **First**: Install `Autmapper` NuGet package for your project from NuGet package explorer.
- **Second**: Make a simple `ViewModel`, which contains only required attributes:

  ```
  public class UserViewModel {
      public int ID {get; set;}
      public string FirstName {get; set;}
      public string LastName {get; set;}
  }
  ```
- **Third**: Initialize your your mapper only for once in `app_start` class like:

  ```
  namespace SampleProject.App_Start {
      public class AutoMapperConfig {
          public static void Initializer() {
              AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {

                  cfg.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>()
              });
           }
       }
  }
  ```
- **Fourth**: Add it's entry in `Global.asax.cs`:

  ```
  namespace SampleProject
  {
      public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
      {
          protected void Application_Start()
          {
              AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
              GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
              FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
              RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
              BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

              // AutoMapper Initializer
              App_Start.AutoMapperConfig.Initializer();
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- **Fifth**: Use it in your controller where you want like this:

  ```
  namespace SampleProject.Controllers
  {
      public class UsersController : Controller
      {
          private DataContext db = new DataContext();

          public ActionResult Index()(
              var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<UserViewModel>>(db.User.ToList());
              return View(model);

          }
      }
  }
  ```
- **Last**: You can create as many maps as you want between your `Models` and `ViewModels` by initializing them once in the `app_start`'s `AutoMapperConfig` class and use them where you want with a simple line of code.

Also you can find a lot of help about `Automapper` if you search about it. Its main website is [here](http://automapper.org/).

---

---

---

### Important:

I am a developer of `ASP.NET MVC 5`. `Automapper` works fine for me every time. I cannot check it on `MVC 3` or older than `MVC 5`.