# How to specify which foreign key column to use in views when scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, scaffolding

How can I specify which foreign key column has to be used in the views when scaffolding?
Im some cases MVC seems to be smart enough to take the right column from the other table, but atm I am having an issue with one and was wondering if I can somehow tell which value to use when scaffolding.

```
public class Tafel
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int TafelNummer { get; set; }
    public virtual int AantalPlekken { get; set; }
    public virtual int CoordX { get; set; }
    public virtual int CoordY { get; set; }
}
```

This is the model that I am having issue's with, it now shows the Id's in a selectbox, but I want it to show `TafelNummer` instead when scaffolding.

Here is a picture that will maybe explain it better --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XNjk.png

[image]

Comment: How do you define your scaffolding selectBox  ?

Comment: Where can I specify that? I'm just scaffolding a controller and views based on a model.

Comment: This is not a web application ?

Comment: It is a mvc Web application.

Comment: So you sure have html content somewhere, is it all automaticaly created ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Yes, that's what scaffolding does. It creates the templates and the controller on itself. I wanna know if I can somehow tell the scaffolder to take a selected column to show in a selectlist, otherwise I'll have to edit it myself (not a big deal but would be nice to get this automaticly done as well).

Comment: If there is no property you can directly change in your programming interface, i d'ont see how you can tell MVC/entity to choose a particular table column, because data Binding is being done on himself without asking you what you exactly want.

Comment: What did you try anyway ? maybe it's just the way you written it.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question @AntoinePelletier :x

Comment: You want the select Box to contain the reel " int TafelNummer { get; set; } " instead of containning the foreign key it is showing right now ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier yes that's what I want, and I know I can manually edit it, but is there also a way to like say in your model or wherever in settings of the scaffolder that it should take another column?

Comment: Ho... I'm not sure you can do that, you see, a model is what it is, it represent the relationship built in your database. MVC generate code according to what it see. But here, it pretty much look like  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647365/how-do-i-choose-which-column-from-the-foreign-table-is-displayed-in-the-view    or : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356180/how-to-select-just-some-fields-from-a-table-in-ef  see if you can attract these guys attention, i would like to put bounty on your question but netheir you netheir i have much reputation to spend

Answer (score 1):

Set the attribute DisplayColumn in your model like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    [DisplayColumn("TafelNummer")]
    public class Tafel
```

EntityFramework sets the MetaData, it takes f.e. the first string property. With this addition you can change that. You only have to re-scaffold.